# how to show StdOut from python script in website

Tags: python, django

I am creating a webpage that allows a user to select options on a form.  When the form is submitted, the choices in the form will be used to dynamically create a python script that will run on the OS.

putting aside all of the security issues with the above, the script will have some `print('this')` or `print('that')` calls that will send out text as part of stdout.  How do I set it so it will show on the webpage for status updates?  This way the user will see what is happening on the script?

Thanks.

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful like: What API are you using to get the data from the client, and how are you posting it back? look into urllib2 for and api that sounds like what you want to do. Not sure exactly what you are going for here. More info pls.

Comment: "dynamically create a python script"... that sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: I am creating a python script that will run a series of data movements.  How it completes this task will be based on parameters sent to it.  what I want to do is automate the script based on a webform that will set the parameters.  The python script will output on stdout normally on the screen when run in command line, but I want to capture that and repeat it back out on the webpage.  Thanks

Comment: Write a script that can handle the data from the webform, not a webform that creates a script!

Comment: I would, but the script calls a series of OS-based commands.

Comment: What do you mean by OS-based commands? Why do you need to dynamically create a python script to use them?

Comment: I am using a third-party technology to manage data.  Certain tasks are only done on the CLI.  This means that I need to construct the cli command and send it to the OS.  I want to capture the cli stdout as it sends text back to the webpage.